# Unknown operator: $and in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am querying mongodb through node.js code.
My mongo documents collection (Patients Collection) has the following structure:+

```
Patient collection

{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59e5c28f37ce021e142e7ead"), 
    "MRN" : "00126389", 
    "Family_Name" : "Jones", 
    "First_Name" : "Lydia", 
    "Father_Name" : "Bob", 
    "Maiden_Name" : "", 
    "Mother_Name" : "n/a", 
    "Spouse_Name" : "", 
    "Address" : "", 
    "Telephone_Nbr" : "", 
    "Patient_Visit" : {
        "Department" : "ER", 
        "Hospital_Status" : "Active", 
        "Case_Nbr" : "17", 
        "Admission_Date" : "01/04/2011 12:00:00 AM", 
        "Admission_Time" : "14:02"

    }
}
```

My query execution code is presented below:

```
mongoClient.connect(mongoConstr, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var query = {
        $and: [{
            "Patient_Visit.Department": "ER"
        }, {
            $or: [{
                "Patient_Visit.Hospital_Status": "Active Left"
            }, {
                "Patient_Visit.Hospital_Status": "Active"
            }]
        }]
    };
    var cursor = db.collection("tbl_Patients").find({
        query
    });
    cursor.forEach(function(doc) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(doc));
    }, function(err) {
        db.close();
        throw (err);
    });
});
```

When the request is executed I get the following error:

```
MongoError: unknown operator: $and
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: which version of Mongo you are using.?

Comment: 3.4.5-rc0-4-g4db4a7c as per db.version() return value

Comment: Someone has already attempted to answer you, Despite getting the callback part wrong the issue is you should be doing `.find(query)` and not `.find({ query })`. That's an ES6 syntax being expanded to `find({ "query": query })` and you don't want that. Hence the error.

Comment: @ElieAsmar - Remove the additional `{}` in your query. Modified query part `var cursor = db.collection("tbl_Patients").find(query);`

Comment: Not the issue but even `query` can be rewritten as `{ "Patient_Visit.Department": "ER", "Patient_Visit.Hospital_Status": { "$in": ["Active Left", "Active"] } }`. `$and` is "implicit" in ALL MongoDB query arguments and rarely ever needed explicitly. Also `$in` is a much shorter version of `$or` when you are applying the condition to the same property.

Answer (score 10):

Replace the {query} with query.

```
var cursor = db.collection("tbl_Patients").find(query);
```

Comment: Possibly string a few words together to say that `query` is different to `{ query }` and why this is so. That might just help the OP understand. Also you don't need the callback in this context.

Comment: "remove the callback". It's not valid for the node native driver. You're thinking mongoose, which is different.

Comment: Thanks  @Rijad, it fixed my problem :)